Laravel Livewire wire:modle and wire:click showing 404 on cpanel but works fine on localhost
Laravel livewire works perfectly on localhost but when deploy to cpanel;  shared hosting,  wire:click and wire:model, not working, for example I have a live data search implemented with livewire, but whenever I try performing a search it displays a 404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server. But livwire components are working correctly.
Whenever I open the browser's console, https://ahotosu-susu-enterprise.com/custom/livewire/update 404 (Not Found).
At first the laravel livwire wasn't working at all but after I configure it to use the @livewireScriptConfig instead of the @livewire, it's working but whenever I trigger a wire:clik or wire:model it shows  404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server. But livwire components are working correctly.
I saw a similar posted by someone , but for the person Livewire was not working on localhost, the solution was for them to configure the livewire and use the @livewireSciptConfig and not the @livescript, I follow and used the solution bcause At first the laravel livwire wasn't working at all when I deployed the project to cpanel but after I configure it to use the @livewireScriptConfig instead of the @livewire, it's working but whenever I trigger a wire:clik or wire:model it shows  404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server. But livwire components are working correctly.
I want livewire to work perfectly as it works on local host.

where does the custom in your url come from?

Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
return Route::post('/custom/livewire/update', $handle);
}).  I got this form livewire official documentation
